# "Задача из Керниган-Ритчи"

Tags: c

> Задача: Напишите программу, печатающую гистограммы частот встречаемости
>   вводимых символов

Для решения как лучше объявить массив, заранее определить в нем все символы или же по мере их встречаемости в потоке добавлять в массив (т.е. если такой символ впервые в массиве то создать ячейку для подсчетов этого символа)? Спасибо!

Comment: У Си очень сложные отношения с работой с памятью (по сравнению с языками со сборкой мусора), и динамически добавлять элементы там не настолько просто, поэтому в случае заранее известного небольшого размера (это ваш случай, 256 или 128 значений по 4 байта - это всего лишь килобайт или половина килобайта) проще выделить сразу. @PinkTux все правильно написал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас однобайтовая кодировка, или речь только о латинице (что очевидно в случае K&R), то достаточно заранее создать массив:

```
size_t char_freq[256] = { 0 };
```

И при вводе символа просто увеличивать счётчик, используя символ как индекс в нём:

```
char_freq[ch]++;
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Но латиница на сколько я понимаю есть и в однобайтовой кодировке! Поэтому для всех символов ваш код подойдет!

Comment: @ActiveNum, но он не подойдёт, например, для русского в UTF8 (а вот в windows-1251 - вполне). Но поскольку это задача из K&R, там явно не имеются в виду такие подробности :-)